# Mentioning system that mimics Facebook's

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've had a horrible problem that I've been wracking my brain for the past two days for, and have yet to come up with a solution. As such, I think this needs someone smarter than I to accomplish.

What I'm trying to build is a textbox that simulates that of Facebook's; essentially, the tagging function.

Now if you've used Facebook, you'll have noticed that Facebook allows you to *tag* people in a comment/post, simply by typing in their name and selecting from a dropdown list. The name of the person you've selected then appears in highlighted text in that very textarea. I've successfully managed to create and populate the dropdown list a combination of JQuery and AJAX, but the tagging process itself is the stumper.

Once a dropdown item has been selected (by Enter or clicking), the query text will be replaced with the tagged name. Now, it's difficult to see how one can give text in a textarea any kind of a highlight, so I've discovered (by inspecting elements in Google Chrome and deleting the textarea node) that the textarea itself is transparent, and there is a white div below "simulating" the text. Highlighted words are placed in a  tag with custom CSS, which gives it that blue background. All of this I've found out myself, and I have successfully simulated this - but I can only do one tag.

Now I've investigated further and found an input type="hidden" element, of class "mentionsHidden". This input element has a value attribute, which dynamically populates itself based on the content of the textarea. So if I typed "ABC", the value of the element becomes "ABC". If I included a tag, say "hi [Rei]!" (where the name in [] is the tag), the value of the element becomes "hi @[member_id:Rei]!".

So I HAVE done my homework. But here comes the part I can't figure out.

I can't figure out how exactly to dynamically populate the hidden input element with the value of the textbox. It's obvious that the underlying div giving the blue tag background is populated from the input element. But the input element is giving me a headache.

You see, I can't do the following:

-I can't simply "copy" the entire value of the current textarea and "paste" it into the input element's value, because that would override any previously tagged people in the input element (after all, the textarea can only possess plaintext).

-Even though I CAN locate the current index of the caret (the flashing black line in the textarea that tells you where you're going to be typing into), that's only for the textarea. Index position 10 in the textarea and in the input element's value might be different things, because this way of "tagging" people will result in adding additional characters to the value String.

-I can't simply do a "replace" of the text I am intending to replace, because there might be other instances of that same text in other parts of the value String.

I know it's a very long and confusing post, but I do hope you get what I mean. I really need a solution and I don't want to use contenteditable, because it's only for HTML5 and some older browsers might not support it.

Yours,
Rei

Answer (score 0):

I hope you were able to come up with, or find, a solution to your problem. Since there doesn't seem to be one here, i'd like to offer one for and anyone who might stumble upon this (as well as you if my assumption was incorrect).

You are going to need to maintain explicit locational data of each existing mention in the `textarea` in the order in which they appear. If, after a modification of the content in `textarea`, the position of a mention in it is changed, you will need to determine which appearance of its value,  if any, will be used to represent it, and appropriately update the locational data of the mention.

With such a collection of data, it becomes trivial to construct the value of `mentionsHidden`, though the existence of such data makes the element unnecessary.

[Mentionator](https://github.com/klawson88/Mentionator) is an existing, robust solution which takes this approach in providing the functionality you are trying to recreate. Considering it is well-structured, easy to follow, and copiously commented, it should be of use to you as either out-of-the box solution or reference material to cite as you roll out your own. It is maintained by yours truly :) .

Comment: Ahh, nice! I stumbled upon this as I, too, need a comment box that handles mentions. I was going to build it myself, but it's quite a task. Instead, I might spend that time converting your jQuery plugin into a React component.